# Adapter to interface camping propane tank like big grilling one

Tags: propane, adapter

I have a propane torch that is made to go on a big grilling propane tank (like you get at the Home Depot). I don't have a tank like that and also where I will be using the torch it would be too big, heavy, and impractical so I would like to use a small camping one.

Which adapter should I get to put on a camping tank to give it a nozzle like a big grilling tank I can hook my torch to?

Comment: When you say "small camping tank" are you talking about a disposable DOT 39 1lb tank? If so, there are a couple makers of 1lb refillable DOT 4BA cylinders out there (I suspect the Manchester Tank ones might be valved as you're looking for, but I'm not 100% sure, 'tis why this isn't an answer)

Comment: You may find that your big torch operates briefly, the tank gets quite cold, and then the flame gets weak. Tank size strongly affects available BTU/Hr from Liquified Propane tanks.

Comment: Yes the disposablr one as well as the blue one they sell for plumbing at Lowes or Home Depot have the same nozzle /socket

Comment: @Ecnerwal I have a very small job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shopping questions are off-topic here.
However, I was able to find what you're looking for by searching for "coleman" (since they're one of the most popular makers of 1lb propane tanks and the camping grills that use them) and "1lb propane grill adapter".

I was able to find [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OXKQQYC) at Amazon in pretty short order.

[image]

Various other adapters likely exist, but I would caution you against trying to make your own with two ends and some tubing. Liquid propane can be 100-200 psi and it's difficult to handle that with DIY tubing.

Comment: +1 especially for the "don't cowboy DIY this fitting" caution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a torch kit that uses a large cylinder then you must also have a hose to connect the torch to the tank. If a longer hose would fix your problem just go to a propane company or a tank gas supplier and have them supply you with a longer hose that will adapt to the existing hose. You can get hoses most any length.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because the hose is made for a big tank

Comment: @amphibient  A hose that you pay to have made  a custom length  can have any fitting end you want pressed on it.

Comment: Show me a picture of your presrent set-up and I will tell you how to proceed